# Removing Label of a Visual Force page form the display

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to remove the area below with the wording Pricing Request Information? This is the label of the Visual Force page and a component added to a tab within a record page. It doesn't hurt any functionality it just takes away from the design of the page:

[image: This is the visualforce page component]

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Did you added inline VF page and it is the section name try putting "." instead of "Pricing Request Information" it will be less visible.

Comment: I'm using the standard visualforce component from the appbuilder for a record page.

Comment: Can you post your component code?